# how to cite a dubbed TV series? APA 6th edition

Tags: citations, apa

I'm quoting lines from a dubbed TV series and I'm not sure how to reference it?

I have looked everywhere and I only found how would you cite an original version.
Help please :)

Comment: Make sure you accept my answer if you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think you would treat this as any other translated work. According to
[this site](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/06/) MLA format would be this:

> Cite as you would any other book. Add "Trans."—the abbreviation for
>   translated by—and follow with the name(s) of the translator(s).
>
> Foucault, Michel. Madness and Civilization: A History of Insanity in
>   the Age of Reason. Trans. Richard Howard. New York: Vintage-Random
>   House, 1988. Print.

Combined that with the television show section:

> Begin with the title of the episode in quotation marks. Provide the
>   name of the series or program in italics. Also include the network
>   name, call letters of the station followed by the city, and the date
>   of broadcast. End with the publication medium (e.g. Television,
>   Radio). For television episodes on Videocassette or DVD refer to the
>   “Recorded Television Episodes” section below.
>
> "The Blessing Way." The X-Files. Fox. WXIA, Atlanta. 19 Jul. 1998.
>   Television.

and I would say the format would be:

> "Episode Name." Show Title. **Trans.** Station or Channel. Station, City. Date of broadcast. Television.